# How to get the functionality of file-loader except I want to process it as a lodash template first

Tags: javascript, webpack, progressive-web-apps

I'm attempting to bundle a web app manifest file, however it references image assets which I also want to be resolved through webpack:

**manifest.webmanifest**

```json
{
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "<%= require('./icons/icon-72x72.png') %>"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have `file-loader` configured to load `.png` assets so that the resulting `src` will be a URL to that asset.

In my main HTML template I'm loading it like this:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="<%= require('./manifest.webmanifest') %>">
```

I'm using `html-webpack-plugin` for this which treats the HTML template as EJS and resolves the `require()` correctly, so there's no problem there. My issue is I would like to do the same for the `manifest.webmanifest` file, but I have no idea what loaders (if any) can achieve the same result as what `html-webpack-plugin` does.

I've tried various combinations of `ejs-loader`, `html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader?force`, `val-loader` and `file-loader` but it always fails because the `require()` never gets resolved by webpack.

Do I need to write my own webpack plugin/loader? Do I have to invoke a "child compiler" (whatever that is) in order to bundle the PNG assets? The webpack documentation for these advanced features is not very clear.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://github.com/unindented/webmanifest-loader

Answer (score 0):

For my specific use case (bundling a web app manifest and all referenced image assets), I can use [webmanifest-loader](https://github.com/unindented/webmanifest-loader) as Ifaruki suggested in the comments.

However I am still interested in a general solution here for any file type, not just a `.webmanifest` kind of file. If I come up with a solution I'll include it here.

Comment: Hi there! I'm running into this exact problem.  Did you happen to find a general solution?  Also, is webmanifest-loader still meeting your needs?

Comment: I cannot recommend webmanifest-loader. Impossible to get my source from https://realfavicongenerator.net/ working. Debugging impossible due to missing detailed errors.